# Action class works in debug mode in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have written the code and that works well when I run this is debugging mode but when I run it in normal mode then I am getting the following exception

```
     org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: 
     Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//*[@id='address-0']/span"}
```

The code I have written is:

```
    WebElement searchBox  = driver.findElement(By.id("search-input"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("somepostcode");
    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
    actions.moveToElement(searchBox);
    WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='address-0']/span"));
    actions.moveToElement(address);
    actions.click();
    actions.perform();
```

I am not able to understand where should I put wait.

I am using eclipse IDE. The functionality works like when I put some postcode in the search box it search for some addresses at runtime and the user has to select any address related to the postcode. Ajax has been used to fetch the postcode

Here search box is a textbox.

Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by breaking the postcode in two parts

```
searchBox.sendKeys("postcodePart1");
searchBox.sendKeys("postcodePart2");
```

There must be kind of on change event was calling.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some wait time before `WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='address-0']/span"));`

Answer (score 1):

Error tells you that, you are trying to create an instance of WebElement "address" before its visible on the page.
Try adding wait before 
`WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='address-0']/span"));`

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, when the script works in debug mode but fails during normal it is almost always the issue with timing. So your page is just not fully loaded at the time you are trying to locate that element.

Place an explicit wait just before your problematic element. It's usually not the best practice to use explicit wait but you can do it as a quick try to see if that solves your problem. If that does you can refactor it into a sturdier solution later.

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you..

```
    WebElement searchBox  = driver.findElement(By.id("search-input"));

    searchBox.sendKeys("somepostcode");

    Actions actions = new Actions(driver);

    actions.moveToElement(searchBox);

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='address-0']/span")));

    WebElement address = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='address-0']/span"));

    actions.moveToElement(address);

    actions.click();

    actions.perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Actionchains, instead directly use the

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "xxxxxx").send_keys(
            "xxxxx")
```

Sometimes in run mode, it moves the focus out of the field which causes it to not enter text.